# How can I test data set in a service callback when testing a controller in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Lets say I have a service which queries some data and sets it in the controller, a little similar to:

```
(Method on controller)

DogService.query(function(data)){
  if(data.isSuccess){
    $scope.IloveDogs = true;
    $scope.dogLovers += 1;
  }
})
```

It is highly simplified, but how would I in my controller test that when calling a mocked `dogService`, that it sets the correct data?

If for simplicity we say that the function isn't asynchronous and deals with promises, I would create and inject a mock to the controller. The mock could look like:

```
var DogService = {
  query: function(){
    return true;
  }
}
```

This unfortunately doesn't run the code where the `$scope.IloveDogs` is set to true, and the `dogLovers` is incremented by one.

Any ideas, since I would rather not have to duplicate the code in my controller from the service to the mocked service?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would normally mock a service in a unit test.
(You didn't mention which testing framework you use, so I am going to assume Jasmine as it's the most popular one at the moment).

I just create a dumb object to act as my mock and then just Jasmine's built-in spy functionality to dictate what it returns. Note that this is syntax for Jasmine 2.0.

I use `$q` to create a promise, and make sure I am able to reference it from my tests so I can resolve it.

```
describe('Spec', function() {

    var scope;
    var catServiceMock;

    var deferredCatCall;

    beforeEach(module('myModule'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $q) {
        scope = $rootScope;

        //Create a mock and spy on it to return a promise
        deferredCatCall = $q.defer();
        catServiceMock = {
            query: function() {}
        };
        spyOn(catServiceMock, 'query').and.returnValue(deferredCatCall.promise);

        //Inject the mock into the controller
        $controller('MyCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            catService: catServiceMock
        });
    }));

    it('proves that cats are better than dogs', function() {
        //resolve the promise that was returned by the mock
        deferredCatCall.resolve({
            isSuccess: true
        });
        //Need to trigger a $digest loop so angular process the resolved promise
        scope.$digest();

        //Check that the controller callback did something
        expect(scope.iLoveCats).toBeTruthy();
    });

});
```

For a service that does not use promises, I would possibly do something like this:

```
describe('Spec', function() {

    var scope;
    var catServiceMock;

    beforeEach(module('myModule'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $q) {
        scope = $rootScope;

        //Create a mock and spy on it to return a value
        catServiceMock = {
            query: function() {}
        };
        spyOn(catServiceMock, 'query').and.returnValue({
            isSuccess: true
        });

        //Inject the mock into the controller
        $controller('MyCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            catService: catServiceMock
        });
    }));

    it('proves that cats are better than dogs', function() {
        //Check that the controller callback did something
        expect(scope.iLoveCats).toBeTruthy();
    });

});
```

The main problem with this approach is that you're forced to dictate what the service will return *before* you instantiate the controller. This means that if you want to test how the controller behaves to different data received from the service you're going to have to have multiple `beforeEach` blocks nested in different `describe` blocks and while it looks at a glance like it's less boilerplate in the test you will end up with a lot more.

This is one of the reasons why I prefer my services to return promises even if they are not asynchronous.

Comment: You were correct about your assumption about jasmin (see the tag ;)). What if you actually didn't have an async method, how would you then do it?

Comment: I have to look at tags too now?! :) All my services use promises, but I'll try to conjure up an example of how I would test a non-promise service.

Comment: @Dofs I've edited in what I would do for a non promise-returning service. And also explained why I would let the service return a promise even if it is not an async operation.

Comment: For the non-promise controller (in this case a resource wrapped in a service serviceModule.factory('CatService', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource('/cats/:id.json', {}, {
        'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: true}}
    );
}]);) it doesn't seem to get into the callback (For info I don't use jasmin 2.0, and uses andReturn(...).)

Comment: I haven't used angular-resource so I'm not sure exactly how that works. I don't even know what the `$resource` function returns so I'm not sure I can help much with that. The snippet I posted was just how I do it for a general case, I'm not sure what modifications would be needed when introducing `$resource` to the mix. That's not saying it can't be done, I just don't know enough about that module.